# Where are these functions differentiable? Proof check!

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I am asked to check where these functions are differentiable. Can someone check what I have done? It seems a little too easy. The functions are:

$$ \bullet \;f(x,y)=|x||y|\qquad \bullet\;g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\;g(0,0)=0$$

**Work:**

For $f:$

- At $(a,b)$ where $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0,\;f_x,f_y$ exist and are continuous in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ so $f$ is differentiable there.
- For fixed $b\neq 0$, we know $f(x,b)$ not differentiable at the origin, so $f$ not differentiable on the line $x=0$ minus the origin, and similarly on the line $y=0$ minus the origin.
- At the origin:

$$\frac{1}{h}(f(h,0)-f(0,0))=0,\quad \frac{1}{k}(f(0,k)-f(0,0))=0$$
So $f$ differentiable there.

For $g:$
following the same steps, I get $g$ differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analysis for $f$ looks good except for the proof that $f$ is differentiable
at the origin.

Note that $|f(x_1,x_2)| \le x_1^2+x_2^2 = \|x\|^2$, so
$\|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0) - 0 (x_1,x_2)^T\| \le \|x\|^2$ which shows that $f$
is differentiable at the origin with derivative $0$ (by $0$ here I mean the
zero mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, or in other words $(0,0)$).

$g(t,t) = {t^2 \over |t|\sqrt{2}} = |t|{1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, which is not
differentiable at $t=0$, hence $g$ cannot be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing: how come my argument for $f$ being differentiable at the origin works for $f$ but not $g$?

Comment: Note that for $x,y$  with the same sign and both non zero, we have $g(x,y) = {f(x,y) \over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Then $f(t,t) = t^2$ which is differentiable at the origin, but $g(t,t) = {1 \over \sqrt{2}} |t|$ which is not.

Comment: Actually, your proof for differentiability at the origin is not quite right, I will add something to my answer.

Comment: Ok I see - but why doesn't my argument itself not work? Should I be saying more when I argue that $f$ *is* differentiable at $(0,0)?$ Thanks again. EDIT: ah great, thanks.